# Why aren't these two divs displayed how I expect them to be?

Tags: html

[This jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wzYry/) shows what I'm talking about, I gave the div in question a red border to show how it's displayed.

I'd expect the #searchwrapper_3 div to go inside the #col_st_cautare one, but for some reason that's not how it works. I've been staring at it for a while now and I got no idea why it's showing like that

I also have an example of it looking ok simply because i've added another element after the #searchwrapper div [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPanV/1/).

Issue's fixed, TIL a div will collapse if it contains only floating elements.

Comment: It would be easier to examine your issue if you separated your style from your markup. In general it's easier to maintain as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a `clear:both;` - see the end of http://jsfiddle.net/wzYry/3/

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;" id="col_st_cautare">
    <div style="float: left;" id="searchwrapper_3">

        .... code ....

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>​
```

On a side note, it may be easier to make `clr` class in your styles.

```
.clr{clear:both;}
```

This way you can use this anytime you need to clear

```
<div class='clr'></div>
```

Comment: Still need to wait one minute.

Answer (score 1):

If a div contains only floating elements, it height will collapse.

You can add a `<div style="clear:both;">` or use some techniques from [this article](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/), for example `overflow:hidden`:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid red;overflow:hidden" id="col_st_cautare">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the child elements inside are floated and parent lost track of the how to wrap them.

Probably the easiest fix for this

```css
#col_st_cautare { overflow: hidden; }
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/wzYry/6/)

Other than this, the stable solution would be to add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before the closing the element.